# Which class will be the median class if n/2 is the cumulative frequency of a class interval?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, median

An example problem:

[image]

When using the textbook formula, Median = L + {[(n/2)-c.f.]/f}*h, where L is the lower limit of the median class, n is the total number of observations, c.f. is the cumulative frequency of the class preceding the median class, f is the frequency of the median class, and h is the class width.

In the example problem, what class shall be taken as the median class 30-40 or 40-50, since n=50. Does the 25th observation lie in the 30-40 class or 40-50 class?

Note: I understand that this may seem like a textbook question, but I assure you my peers and teachers are having mixed answers. I have searched Google and have also found mixed answers either saying that: 1. the median class contains the median, thus 30-40 is the median class, 2. when finding medians, we follow the exclusive model thus, 40-50 is the median class. Anything helps, even a link to a similar question if this is a duplicate.

Comment: I suspect you will get the same answer taking the median class as $30-40$ or $40-50$.

Comment: In answer to your question: the $25$th observation is in the $30-40$ class while the $26$th observation is in the $40-50$ class.  So half the observations are at $40$ or below and  half the observations are at $40$ or above.